# Can't I use getters and setters in an Angular's httpclient result?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, observable

In my angular project I have a method that returns a User class from the backend:

```
export class User {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  my_list: Array<string>;

  get otherNameForMyList() : Array<string> {
    return this.my_list;
  }

  set otherNameForMyList(newList  : Array<string>) {
    this.my_list = newList;
  }
}
```

so I call the backend this way:

```
export class UserService {    
  getUserFromBE(login: string): Observable<User> {
    return this.http
      .get<User>(`${environment.apiUrl}/user/${login}`)
      .pipe(catchError(this.processHTTPMsgService.handleError));
  }
}
```

But when I call this method and subscribe the result I can't use otherNameForMyList:

```
let user = new User();
userService.getUserFromBE('mylogin').subscribe(async (u : User)=>{
  console.log(u.otherNameForMyList); // undefined
}
```

yet if I make it this way it works:

```
let user = new User();
userService.getUserFromBE('mylogin').subscribe(async (u : User)=>{
  console.log(u.my_list); // ok result
}
```

also console.log(u) returns Object type, not User type as it should be.

Now, if I declared the ": Observable" as result type from the httpclient call in getUserFromBE, shouldn't u be of User type ? Can I force it to be ?

Obviously the api is returning just my_list field.

Can anyone please explain why u is Object and not User ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The generic methods on the `HttpClient` will use type assertion to on the deserialized json result. Example: `.get<User>` would still return an object but type assertion can now be used in the static code to treat that returned instance as a `User`. It does *not* mean the returned instance is of type `User`.

If you want an actual instance of `User` you should use `map` and create an instance of `User` to be returned to the caller.

Example:

```
export class UserService {    
  getUserFromBE(login: string): Observable<User> {
    return this.http
      .get<{id:string;name:string;my_list:Array<string>}>(`${environment.apiUrl}/user/${login}`)
      .pipe(map(user => {
        var result = new User();
        result.id = user.id;
        result.name = user.name;
        result.my_list = user.my_list;
        return result;
      }),catchError(this.processHTTPMsgService.handleError));
  }
}
```